# Однородные члены

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в словосочетании "мистическая религиозная составляющая"?Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Я вижу всего два варианта этого словосочетания:

> "мистическая религиозная составляющая"

и

> "мистическая, религиозная составляющая"

Мне кажется, что они оба возможны в зависимости от того, что конкретно вкладывалось в него в изначальном тексте. Если, например, речь идет о равноправных качествах, то явно второй. Если качества уточняют друг друга - тогда первый.